# when and how to use overloaded operator( )

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

In lots of C++ book I have seen they  use overload  operator '( )' .

I still don't understand when and how to use it.
 For example I know how to implement or overload '+' operator for a class or '='. I also exactly know when to use these operators but just cant understand about operator '()'.
 Can some please guide me may be by an example. I have googled and I found about tutorials related to overloading .

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=overloading%20parenthesis%20operator - what else is there to understand?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/q/356950/1870232

Comment: if essentially turn your class into a functor, ie, you can use it as a function

Comment: Cool got it. from the link by POW. Thanks